# Add default parameter regarding time SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I am developing a report on task performance based on their working shift. Day shift will start on 9am to 9pm and night shift will start from 9pm to 9am. I would like to display data based on their current working shift as example, if someone is working on day shift and view report on 8pm, the report will show from range 9am to 8pm only and if user working for night shift, the report will only show from 9pm to 9am range

I have a dataset and parameter which is @begin_date and @end_date (eg. Monday, Tuesday...), @begin_hour and @end_hour. I got column "time" where the task complete.

Can someone help me?

EDIT:

Sorry, can you guide me, this is my propose sample code. Let say the current date is monday

If time <= 21 begin show 9am to (current time, limit 9pm monday) end Else if time >= 21 Begin Show 9pm to (current time, limit 9am tuesday)
End

How can i do this in sql?

Comment: How can the report know what shift the user works?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a parameter at all.   Add the logic into the stored proc or query that returns the results.  Only show results from the beginning of the shift up to the current time.